# MySQL - Multiple Sub-Queries Causing Performance Issues

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I'm trying to pull some data together via MySql query which I'm trying to show;

```
AgentName, 
AgentGroupCode,
YearToDateRevenue, 
7DayRevenue, 
YTDOrderCount, 
7DayOrderCount.
```

As it stands, right now, I'm using multiple sub queries to pull the YTD and 7 day details, and this is causing huge strain on the system - it's taking around 130 seconds to complete, which is not acceptable in my eyes.

I was wondering if there is a much slicker way to produce this? My current code is as follows:

```
SET @YTDStart = '2017-01-01';
Set @YTDEnd = '2017-05-07';


SELECT b.AgentRef, a.Name, a.AgentGroup,
(
  SELECT sum(b.basicprice) from bookings b WHERE b.bookingdate BETWEEN @YTDStart AND @YTDEnd
) as YTDRevenue,

(
  SELECT sum(b.basicprice) from bookings b WHERE b.bookingdate BETWEEN @WeekStart AND @WeekEnd
) as 7DayRevenue
#Similar code for the Count but will exclude for this example.

FROM bookings b 
INNER JOIN Agent a ON b.agentref = a.code
GROUP BY b.agentref
```

Comment: Please tag your question correctly. Are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server (since you tagged 'tsql')? Query optimization answers depends on which SQL product you use, and tagging your question accurately will attract the attention of the people who can help give the best answers.

Answer (score 0):

There really shouldn't be a need for subqueries for this kind of data, instead you can use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT b.AgentRef, a.Name, a.AgentGroup
   , SUM(CASE WHEN b.bookingdate BETWEEN @YTDStart AND @YTDEnd THEN b.basicprice ELSE 0 END) AS YTDRevenue
   , SUM(CASE WHEN b.bookingdate BETWEEN @WeekStart AND @WeekEnd THEN b.basicprice ELSE 0 END) AS `7DayRevenue`
#Similar code for the Count but will exclude for this example.
FROM bookings b 
INNER JOIN Agent a ON b.agentref = a.code
WHERE /* assuming week date range within year date range, 
         and you only care about b.agentrefs that "occurred" in the time frame 
      */
b.bookingdate BETWEEN @YTDStart AND @YTDEnd
GROUP BY b.agentref
;
```

Technically, if the comment I put in the `WHERE` is correct, the YTD aggregation does not need to be conditional.

Comment: Thankyou, I'll give this a try and report back!

Comment: I've just tried this, the YTD count and Revenue add up fine. The 7 day revenue also adds up fine. However, the 7 day count seems to return the same value as the YTD. Would you have any explanation why this is happening?

Comment: @alfieph what @values are you using, and what is the aggregation you are using for the count? _If you are using `COUNT(CASE...ELSE 0...)` then the answer is that `COUNT` counts `0` so it should be `ELSE NULL` (because `COUNT` ignores nulls)._

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head there! Thanks for your help on this, its really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use with a join on the aggregated  tables

```
SELECT b.AgentRef, a.Name, a.AgentGroup, t1.YTDRevenue, t2.7DayRevenue
FROM bookings b 
INNER JOIN Agent a ON b.agentref = a.code

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT b.AgentRef, sum(b.basicprice)  as YTDRevenue 
    from bookings b 
    WHERE b.bookingdate BETWEEN @YTDStart AND @YTDEnd
    GROUP BY b.agentref
) t1 on t1.AgentRef = b.agentref
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT b.AgentRef, sum(b.basicprice) as 7DayRevenue
    from bookings b 
    WHERE b.bookingdate BETWEEN @WeekStart AND @WeekEnd
    GROUP BY b.agentref
) t2 t2.AgentRef = b.agentref
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using left joins instead of sub-select. Also, be sure you have indexes on the columns used in the ON and WHERE clauses.

```
SET @YTDStart = '2017-01-01';
SET @YTDEnd = '2017-05-07';
SET @WeekStart = '2017-05-01';
SET @WeekEnd = '2017-05-07';

SELECT 
    b.AgentRef, 
    a.Name, 
    a.AgentGroup,
    SUM(b.basicprice) as `YTDRevenue`,
    SUM(c.basicprice) as `7DayRevenue`,
    COUNT(b.basicprice) as `YTDCount`,
    COUNT(c.basicprice) as `7DayCount`
FROM Agent a
LEFT JOIN bookings b 
ON b.agentref = a.code AND b.bookingdate BETWEEN @YTDStart AND @YTDEnd
LEFT JOIN bookings c
ON b.agentref = a.code AND b.bookingdate BETWEEN @WeekStart AND @WeekEnd
GROUP BY b.agentref
```

Comment: I like this answer but the columns don't have index's so this was running for a while and then locked up MySQL workbench.

Comment: Well, as mentioned in the answer, add indexes to those columns.